# What languages does the Zoom transcription feature support?

Tags: audio, zoom.us

The popular video conferencing tool [Zoom](https://zoom.us) supports recording of meetings and automatic transcription of recorded meetings via the webclient. I couldn't find any information on the supported languages on the Zoom website. Does Zoom speech recognition work with any  languages other than English?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please make the question focused on using the Zoom web client, show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Have you already reviewed the Zoom help website?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Audio transcription for cloud recordings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115004794983-Audio-transcription-for-cloud-recordings):

> Audio transcription only supports English.